# How to specify the include and lib path of pgm library when making PCA-SIFT code

Tags: linux, makefile, include-path, pkg-config

I am trying to make the PCA-SIFT code (pcasift-0.91nd.tar.gz) in this webpage: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~yke/pcasift/. After running ./configure which is OK, the make command report that the C compiler can not find header pgm.h:

> image.cc:18:22: fatal error: pgm.h: No such file or directory
>         #include 
>                         ^ compilation terminated.

There is a webpage in internet which discussed this issue: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1918422. A solution was stated at the end:

> Apparently, the header files are in the directory /usr/include/pgm-5.1
>   - the preferred way to get this into your include directories when compiling is to use pkgconfig. You will need to add something like
>   `pkg-config --cflags openpgm-5.1` at the end of your compilation
>   command to get the right headers and add `pkg-config --libs
>   openpgm-5.1` to your linking command.

, but I cannot understand it. Specifically, what does "add `pkg-config --cflags openpgm-5.1` at the end of your compilation command" mean? What should I do, to add `pkg-config --cflags openpgm-5.1` literally or the results this command returns in terminal? And add to what file? The Makefile is generated by ./configure. Should I add to Makefile or ./configure? I have successfully install libpgm-dev and they are really in /usr/include/pgm-5.1. The command `pkg-config --cflags openpgm-5.1` returns `-I/usr/include/pgm-5.1 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pgm-5.1/include` and command `pkg-config --libs openpgm-5.1` returns `-lpgm -lpthread -lm`.

Since that thread was closed, I have to ask here. Hoping someone familiar with Linux compiling process could help me with this issue. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem myself.

Everything in the ubuntuforums.org webpage mentioned in the original question is wrong; that's why I met with so many problems.

Wrong 1: It's wrong to install libpgm-dev using `sudo apt-get install libpgm-dev`.
We should download Netpbm, and run the following command after uncompression:

```
./configure      //type none on prompt if you don't have JPEG, TIFF, etc. libraries
make
sudo make package pkgdir=netpbmpkg
sudo ./installnetpbm
sudo rm -f -r /netpbmpkg/
```

Then Netpbm is installed on Ubuntu.

Wrong 2. The include path returned by `pkg-config --cflags` is wrong

By default, The include path shold be `/usr/local/netpbm/include` and the lib path is `/usr/local/netpbm/lib`.

Wrong 3. The linking option `-lpgm` returned by `pkg-config --libs` is wrong

The correct linking option should be `-lnetpbm`.

Following the right way, I can successfully compile the project in Netbeans (forget about command line make).

Comment: hey I'm facing the same problem Could you tell mehow this line  should be executed" sudo make package pkgdir=netpbmpkg" I do not know what to put in. Also you have mentioned what is wrong, could you tell how to set it right, or if you could point out  any detailed procedure that would be nice too..